# how to send values from the form from one page to another without reloading it

Tags: php, mysql

file name is course.php. i have a dropdown in which all the courses from course table are displayed. i want that when i click on ADD link the course add to the grid without reloading the page.

```
    <select name="course" class="text-field" >';
    echo'<option value="-1" selected> Courses</option>';
    $query1=mysql_query("select * from course");
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
    echo '<option value="'.$rows['crs_id'].'">'.$rows['crs_name'].'</option>';
    echo'</select>'; 
    echo '<a href="course.php?action=add">  ADD  </a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `AJAX`. 
it can add a item without reloading it

**Ajax** is a set of web development techniques utilizing many web technologies used on the client-side to create asynchronous Web applications.

it is a good skill.